# Make all English text in typewriter family in LyX

Tags: fonts, lyx

I'm writing a document in two different languages in LyX and want all English text to appear in the typewriter family (not necessary in the LyX editor itself, but in the output file).

Is there a way to do it automatically, instead of changing the font style manually for each word?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which command do you use to introduce English text?

Comment: @Bernard thanks! I'm using F12

Comment: Add `\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Courier}` to the document preamble.

Comment: @tush thanks! Can I do the same thing with Times New Roman font? I like it better than Courier.

Comment: Indeed, it works with Times New Roman as well, thank you!

Comment: @tush I propose that tush adds an answer (to get this out of the unanswered queue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using XeTeX engine, you can simply change the font, with [fontspec](https://ctan.com/pkg/fontspec)'s command `setmainfont`:

```
\setmainfont{⟨Font Family Name goes here⟩}
```

If some other language is set up (by babel or polyglossia), then you should use

```
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{⟨Font Family Name goes here⟩}
```

`Courier New` and `Latin Modern Mono` are two font families that come with standard TeX distributions.